# QWidget cannot catch ESCAPE, BACKSPACE or C-x key press events

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am catching key press events by overriding the `KeyPressEvent` method of my class, inheriting from `QWidget`, but I cannot see key *press* events for the ESCAPE and BACKSPACE keys, as well as `C-x` or again `C-c`. I can see key *release* events though. Who catches them ?

```
class KeyCaptureWidget(QWidget):
    # init…

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        logging.info("key press: {}".format(key))

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        key_code = event.key()
        logging.info("key release: {}".format(key_code))
```

The difference between `C-x` and say `C-b` is the following:

- pressing `C-b` prints: control is pressed, b is pressed, b is released, control is released.
- pressing `C-x` prints: control is pressed, [nothing], x is released, control is released.

In my QWidget, I use a QVBoxLayout to which I put two QWebEngine views. I tried to override the key press method of the QWebEngineView, but they don't seem to catch anything (and this is the behaviour I expected).

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.qtwindow = KeyCaptureWidget()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.view1 = QWebEngineView()  # or a custom one to override keyPressEvent
        # self.view2 = the same

        self.layout.addWidget(self.view1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view2)
        self.qtwindow.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.qtwindow.show()
```

I tried to catch these with **event filters** on my QWidget class but again, no luck: I see only a key release for ESC or BACKSPACE.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        logging.info("event filter: {}".format(event))
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            logging.info(" event filter key PRESS")
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease:
            logging.info(" event filter key RELEASE")
        return True
```

How can I catch them ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events do not necessarily propagate among all widgets, if a widget consumes it then it will no longer propagate to the parent. In the case of the keyboard events will only be consumed first by the widget that has the focus, in your case QWebEngineView consumes them before and prevents it from being projected in other widgets. If you want to hear events from the keyboard of a window then you must use the QShortcuts, and for that you must create a QShortcut:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: `QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C")`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>: `QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+X")`
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>: `QtGui.QKeySequence("Escape")`
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd>: `QtGui.QKeySequence("Backspace")`

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_view1 = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.m_view2 = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.m_view1.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890831"))
        self.m_view2.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://doc.qt.io/"))

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_view1)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_view2)

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), self, activated=self.on_Ctrl_C
        )

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+X"), self, activated=self.on_Ctrl_X
        )

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence("Escape"), self, activated=self.on_Escape
        )

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence("Backspace"), self, activated=self.on_Backspace
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_Ctrl_C(self):
        print("Ctrl+C")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_Ctrl_X(self):
        print("Ctrl+X")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_Escape(self):
        print("Escape")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_Backspace(self):
        print("Backspace")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```